# Need to create a Hash using user input in Ruby

Tags: ruby

The goal is to get the user to enter 3 separate numbers and have the script store those in a Hash, output the values, and then add all the numbers in the hash.  The script I'm working on keeps erroring out, and I was hoping for some guidance on how to correct it.

```
#!/user/bin/ruby
userhash=Hash.new()
puts "Enter first number"
userhash=[:num1=>gets.chomp]
puts "Enter second number"
userhash=[:num2=>gets.chomp]
puts "Enter third number"
userhash=[:num3=>gets.chomp]
puts "The numbers entered were"
userhash.each_value {|value| puts value}
puts "the sum is #{userhash.inject(:+)}"
```

I just finished doing this as an array with no issues and thought that doing it as a hash would be quite similar.  Obviously it's not working as intended.  Help is appreciated.

```
Error: rb:15:in '<main>': undefined method 'each_value' for [{:num3=>"3"}]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I entered values 1, 2, 3 when prompted to test.

UDPATE: Orde's method got helped me get this to work

```
#!/user/bin/ruby
userhash=Hash.new()
puts "Enter first number"
userhash[:num1]=gets.chomp.to_f
puts "Enter 2nd number"
userhash[:num2]=gets.chomp.to_f
puts "Enter 3rd number"
userhash[:num3]=gets.chomp.to_f
puts "The number you entered were "
userhash.each_value {|value| puts value}
puts "The sum of those number is #{userhash.each_value.inject(:+)}"
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Added error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeatedly reassigning to `userhash` and assigning an array (e.g. `[:num1=>gets.chomp]`).  Because `Array` doesn't have an `each_value` method, an `undefined method` is thrown.

```
userhash=Hash.new()
puts userhash.class                  #=> Hash
puts "Enter first number"
userhash=[:num1=>gets.chomp]
puts userhash.class                  #=> Array
```

To associate a value with a key, the [element assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D-label-Element+Assignment) syntax is `hash_name[key] = value`:

```
userhash=Hash.new()
puts "Enter first number"
userhash[:num1] = gets.chomp
puts "The numbers entered were"
userhash.each_value {|value| puts value}
puts userhash.class                  #=> Hash
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of mistakes in this code. Here's a refactored version:

```
# Declare an empty hash with the { } notation
entries = { }

# Request input N times
(1..3).each do |n|
  puts "Enter number %d" % n

  # Add this entry to the hash, convert it to an integer with to_i
  entries[:"num#{n}"] = gets.chomp.to_i
end

# Add the numbers together and have a default of 0 in case the array
# is empty.
puts "the sum is %d" % entries.values.inject(0, :+)
```

Your original code was re-defining the `userhash` variable as an array with a hash in it. This new code organizes things into a single hash with multiple entries, though given how it's used, this isn't necessary. Instead you could do this:

```
sum = 0

(1..3).each do |n|
  puts "Enter number %d" % n
  sum += gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "the sum is %d" % sum
```

Comment: I appreciate your help tadman.  I was obviously completely lost.

Comment: The way you get un-lost is by trying, which you've done, so there's no harm in that.